# NullPointerException in mine sweeper program

Tags: java, class, inheritance, nullpointerexception

So I'm a computer science student and a fledgling programmer in Java. Someone asked me to help them on an assignment where they have to create a pretty basic minesweeper program. This program doesn't utilize flagging mines at all, but aside from that it is functionally the same as any other mine sweeper game.

I'm running into a NullPointerException when I try to run the program. I've researched what this could mean and now know that this should really be a NoObjectException or DereferenceException, but I'm still no closer to solving the issue.

This exception arises when the makeField method of the Tile class is called. Also, I'm really trying to wrap my head around proper inheritance, static vs. non-static, public vs. private, and how all of these inter-relate,  so I'm sorry if this is a total noob question.

So, I have a main file, a Tile super class, and two sub-classes of the tile class- Bomb and Flat. Bomb is a tile with a bomb in it, and Flat is any tile that isn't a bomb.

```
public class MineSweeperMain{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dimension;
    Tile[][] gameBoard;

    System.out.print("Enter the dimension of the board you would like to play on:\t");
    dimension = kybd.nextInt();

    gameBoard = Tile.makeField(dimension);
    Tile.printField(gameBoard, dimension);
}

}
```

//

```
public class Tile {

static Random rand = new Random();

boolean isBomb;
boolean isRevealed;
int posX, posY;
int noOfAdjacentMines;

public Tile()
{
    isRevealed = false;
}

public static int detectMines(Tile[][] board, int dimensions)
{
    int detectedMines = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < dimensions; j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j].isBomb)
                detectedMines++;
        }
    }
    return detectedMines;
}

public static Tile[][] makeField(int dimensions)
{   
    int rowOfMines = dimensions / 3;
    int randomInRow;

    Tile[][] Board = new Tile[dimensions][dimensions];

    for(int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j <= rowOfMines; j++)
        {
        randomInRow = rand.nextInt(dimensions);
        Board[i][randomInRow] = new Bomb();
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < dimensions; j++)
        {
            if(!Board[i][j].isBomb)
                Board[i][j] = new Flat();
        }
    return Board;               
}

public static void printField(Tile[][] board, int dimensions)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= dimensions; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= dimensions; j++)
        {
            if(i ==0)
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            else if(j == 0)
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            else
            {
                if(board[i-1][j-1].isRevealed && !board[i-1][j-1].isBomb)
                    System.out.print(board[i-1][j-1].noOfAdjacentMines + " ");  
                else
                    System.out.print("# ");
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

//

```
public class Flat extends Tile{

public Flat()
{
    noOfAdjacentMines = 0;
    isBomb = false;
    isRevealed = false;
}
}
```

//

```
public class Bomb extends Tile{
public Bomb()
{
    isBomb = true;
    isRevealed = false;
}

}
```

//

Comment: Where is the NullPointerException? (Which Statement?)

Comment: READ the stack trace of the exception. It isn't meaningless garbage. It tells you exactly where in the code the exception happens, and what the whole call stack was when the exception was thrown. If you don't understand it, post it in your question, and tell us which line of the code it points to.

Comment: 1) Classes should start with uppercase, variables names with lowercase. 2) `System.out.println` is a handy debugging tool for a simple NullPointerException, just to see what reference is actually null, and working back from there.

Comment: You are absolutely right that the name NullPointerException doesn't really reach the heart of the matter.  C# has the NullRefererenceException, which is a better name because languages like Java and C# have references and not pointers (unless you are writing/using C# code that is explicitly marked as unsafe).  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx for more on the distinction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is in the second loop of the `makeField` method I think.

When you check `if(!Board[i][j].isBomb)` That particular value is going to be null because you have not filled your array fully yet. There are a couple random bombs placed by the first loop, but the rest of the values are null.

I would recommend reversing your loops. First loop through everything and make the whole board out of `Flat`s without checking anything.

Then in your second loop, you will just overwrite a couple `Flat`s with `Bomb`s

The other solution is just to make this tiny modification and check for null:

`if(null == Board[i][j] || !Board[i][j].isBomb)`

Note that if you take this solution, the null check must be **FIRST**. This is because of something called [short-circuting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

The reason I recommend my first solution though of switching the loops is because it eliminates 1 extra comparison, not huge deal, but you never know...

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much. I understand now. I'll use your first suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of questions there, but to answer the main question of why you are getting a null pointer:

```
Board[i][randomInRow] = new Bomb();
```

In the above code, you are placing Bombs randomly around the board in each row.  Note that this will only set a value to a subset of the squares.

Then you loop through EVERY square and do the following:

```
if(!Board[i][j].isBomb) Board[i][j] = new Flat();
```

The problem is that, if the square was not assigned to be a bomb, it has not been assigned anything, so it is null.  When you call `isBomb` on something that is null, you get a null pointer.  This test should instead be to check if `Board[i][j] == null`.

That being said, you may want to start smaller than this.  While being relatively basic as far as games go, I think you need more of a basic understanding of java before diving into something like this.

Answer (score 5):

I think I see the problem. When you make the board you set bombs to random elements in a row. Then you check all of them to see whether there is a bomb there.

```
if(!Board[i][j].isBomb) // What if board[i][j] is not set? Null Pointer Exception
                Board[i][j] = new Flat();
```

Is this useful?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not filling your `Bomb` array.

You will need something like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < dimensions; j++){
            Board[i][j] = new Tile(); // or something
            if(!Board[i][j].isBomb()) // use an accessor
            Board[i][j] = new Flat();
        }
    return Board;               
}
```

Comment: That is where the problem is, but this solution would overwrite all of the bombs he just placed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the board is not initialized with a default tile.

You have:

```
Tile[][] Board = new Tile[dimensions][dimensions];
```

and then you randomly assign bombs:

```
Board[i][randomInRow] = new Bomb();
```

The tiles that were not bombs are still null. So calling this will result in NPE(NullPointerException):

```
if (!Board[i][j].isBomb)
```

To solve this change that line to:

```
if (!Board[i][j] == null)
```

So, if the board at that current position is null surely it wasn't initialized as a Bomb.
There are other ways you could turn and twist the code to solve this, but this is the easiest I thought of.

Answer (score -1):

When you declare your multi dimension array you don't get any objects created in your arrays. You need something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < dimensions; j++) {
        Board[i][j] = new Tile();
    }
}
```

Comment: @JamesMontagne You are right, didn't see that the array was declared with both dimensions. Of course you can create the array the way I wrote, that is how you would make a multi dimensional array with different length for each sub array (to make a triangular array for example).

Comment: Yeah, I take back the 2nd part.  Also, just FYI, not my downvote.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Well, you had a valid comment. Thanks.